# Return an object that contains another object from a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, object, return

Why does the value in drawManifestoGlobal change after the first time `cout` is called on it?  It looks like `canvas.panel.drawManifestoGlobal` gets destructed - why?

How can I get around this?

```
#include <iostream>

class DrawManifestoGlobal {
public:
    int value = 2;
};

class Panel {
public:
    void setDrawManifestoGlobal(DrawManifestoGlobal & _drawManifestoGlobal);
    DrawManifestoGlobal * drawManifestoGlobal;
};

class Canvas {
public:
    Canvas() {};
    Canvas(DrawManifestoGlobal _drawManifestoGlobal);
    DrawManifestoGlobal drawManifestoGlobal;
    Panel panel;
};


class SerDe {
public:
    Canvas doSerDe();
};

Canvas SerDe::doSerDe() {

    DrawManifestoGlobal drawManifestoGlobal;
    drawManifestoGlobal.value = 99; 
    Canvas canvas(drawManifestoGlobal);

    return canvas;
}

Canvas::Canvas(DrawManifestoGlobal _drawManifestoGlobal) {
    drawManifestoGlobal = _drawManifestoGlobal;
    panel.setDrawManifestoGlobal(drawManifestoGlobal);
}

void Panel::setDrawManifestoGlobal(DrawManifestoGlobal &_drawManifestoGlobal) {
    drawManifestoGlobal = &_drawManifestoGlobal;
}

int main () {
    SerDe serde;
    Canvas canvas;
    canvas = serde.doSerDe();

    std::cout << canvas.panel.drawManifestoGlobal->value << std::endl; // prints 99
    std::cout << canvas.panel.drawManifestoGlobal->value << std::endl; // prints 0 (!!!)
}
```

Regards to implementation requirement: Canvas owns Panel and DrawManifestoGlobal, and Panel itself has pointer to Canvas's DrawManifestoGlobal so that any changes that occur to it from Canvas are visible to Panel.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the value in `drawManifestoGlobal` change after the first time `cout` is called on it? It looks like `canvas.panel.drawManifestoGlobal` gets destructed - why?

`drawManifesttoGlobal` inside the `doSerDe()` function is a local variable that expires at the end of the scope, yet you are setting a pointer to it (`Panel::drawManifestoGlobal`) and passing the pointer outside the function (through the return of `canvas`). So you have undefined behavior for accessing the value of an already destructed object. The compiler is perfectly within its rights to print two different values for the same object.

If you really need a pointer (which you don't) you will want to dynamically allocate `drawManifestoGlobal` (preferably with a `unique_ptr`).

```
class Panel {
public:
  void setDrawManifestoGlobal(std::unique_ptr<DrawManifestoGlobal> _drawManifestoGlobal);
  std::unique_ptr<DrawManifestoGlobal> drawManifestoGlobal;
};

Canvas SerDe::doSerDe() {
  std::unique_ptr<DrawManifestoGlobal> drawManifestoGlobal(make_unique<DrawManifesttoGlobal>());
  drawManifestoGlobal.value = 99; 
  return {std::move(drawManifestoGlobal)};
}

void Panel::setDrawManifestoGlobal(std::unique_ptr<DrawManifestoGlobal> drawManifestoGlobal) {
  drawManifestoGlobal = std::move(_drawManifestoGlobal);
}
```

The truth is that you don't need pointers anywhere in your code!

Comment: Thank you for your help!
1) But why does DrawManifestoGlobal get destructed?  It gets created in Canvas, and then (a copy of) Canvas gets passed back to main.  Shouldn't that Panel and DrawManifestoGlobal come along for the ride?
2) What's a way to do this without pointers where Panel's DrawManifestoGlobal's internal variables are always the same as the values in Canvas's DrawManifestoGlobal?

Comment: @Saro 1) It gets created in the `Canvas` constructor but its lifetime is tied to the body of the constructor. After the end of the function body `_drawManifesttoGlobal` is destructed, but you still have a pointer to it that you are using outside the constructor (in main). Even if it is a copy of `Canvas` passed into main, only the internal *pointer* of `Panel::drawManifestoGlobal` is copied, not the object it points to. 2) I didn't know you wanted its internal variables to be the same. In that case you should use a pointer.